# Can't import .jar into Eclipse Android Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

So I have imported by two .jar files into the `libs` folder using the following method:

1. Right click on libs > Import > Import File System and then bring them in.
2. Once they get brought in, right click libs > Build Path > Configure Build Path and add them to the Build Path of the project.

However, when I imported the package I needed to use in my project, it gave me the error "The import org.codehaus cannot be resolved."

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: more details needed. Show some screenshots of your eclipse build path etc, link to the library api you expect to be using

Comment: Here is the link to the library I'm using:

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload

Edit: I want to use the Core and DataBind 2.x version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the jars in the `libs` folder of your project as you have done. Then, right click on the jar, go to `Build Path` -> `Configure Build Path`. In the `Libraries` tab click `Add JARs...` and select the library jar. Then, go to the `Order and Export` tab and make sure that the library jar is checked.

Here's some info I found on integrating Jackson libraries: http://supersabrams.com/blog/?p=81

Comment: There is no `Add as Library...` option in my right click menu.

Comment: My bad, this was for Android Studio. I will edit my answer in just a second.

Comment: OK, so the jar was not checked in that tab, but even when it is checked, I get the same error that the import cannot be resolved.

Comment: Does the jar show up in Referenced Libraries under your project?

Comment: Actually, just double checked the spelling (I had deleted my import after it didn't work just to remove the error and work on other parts of the code) and that got it. It works like a charm now!

Answer (score 0):

You only  need to put them in the libs folder.
Remove them from the build path as this will cause problems with libraries declaration.